# Why is the code starting from the end and ending at the beginning of the string?

Tags: c++, c++20

The question asks you to take in a string and for each position, you can delete that digit and insert the digit min(9,s[i]) anywhere in the string. What is the smallest lexographical number you can make?

I'm just confused on why the for loop starts at the last digit(size-1) and goes backwards. I've tried starting from the s[0] but the answer is always wrong compared to starting at s[n-1]. Can someone explain why? Thanks!

```
using namespace std;

void solve(){
    string s; 
    cin>>s;
    int size=s.size(); //set size=num of characters in string s
    char mn='9'; //minimum=9
    for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){     //set i to last element; if i>=0; --i
            mn=min(mn,s[i]); //set mn=minimum between mn and s[i]       *note for last element, min(9,s[n-1])
        if(s[i]!='9' && s[i]>mn){       //if s[i] not equal to 9 and s[i] greater than mn
            s[i]++;                 // add one to s[i]
        }
    }
    sort(s.begin(),s.end());        //sort the string
    cout<<s<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        solve();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: That‘s what a lexographical comparison does.

Comment: Work through an example by hand.   You'll see that the behaviour differs depending on which way the loop runs.